# Remove 'None' from textbox without using codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a shipping label that I generate using multibindings, like the following:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxShippingLabel" Margin="0,10,-2,2" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}&#x0a;{2}&#x0a;{3}&#x0a;{4}&#x0a;{5}&#x0a;{6} {7}">
            <Binding ElementName="dataGridOutstandingOrders" Path="SelectedItem[FirstName]" />
            <Binding ElementName="dataGridOutstandingOrders" Path="SelectedItem[Surname]" />
            <Binding ElementName="dataGridOutstandingOrders" Path="SelectedItem[Department]" />
            <Binding ElementName="dataGridOutstandingOrders" Path="SelectedItem[Organisation]" />
            <Binding ElementName="dataGridOutstandingOrders" Path="SelectedItem[Street]" />
            <Binding ElementName="dataGridOutstandingOrders" Path="SelectedItem[Suburb]" />
            <Binding ElementName="dataGridOutstandingOrders" Path="SelectedItem[State]" />
            <Binding ElementName="dataGridOutstandingOrders" Path="SelectedItem[Postcode]" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This works great, except when data such as organisation or department comes back as 'None' (which happens in the cases of orders made by individuals). When that happens the label represents as the following:

[image]

Is there a way I can use XAML to identify when a binding is returning 'None' and use an alternate `StringFormat`?

Comment: Are you open to using a MultiValueConverter instead of StringFormat?

Comment: Will `TargetNullValue` help you ??

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Totally open, but haven't been exposed to them before. Is it appropriate in use cases like this?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Unfortunately not. The item source isn't returning Null but 'None' - it's not my codebase (I'm adding a feature only) so I don't believe I can change this without introducing risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you requested a solution without codebehind. However I don't think that is possible cause you want to have some "ifs" inside your string format. This is also not possible in code behind (see also the extension method I've provided).

If you can extend the `SelectedItem` (whatever that might be), I would put a property there. This is maybe helpful in the future (e.g. send label over API). You could also use an `ExtensionMethod` if you cannot access the codebase.

You have at least 2 "workarounds":

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        List<OrderViewModel> newList = new List<OrderViewModel>();

        newList.Add(new OrderViewModel() { FirstName = "foo", LastName = "bar", Organization = "SO", ZipCode = "666" });
        newList.Add(new OrderViewModel() { LastName = "bar", Organization = "SO", ZipCode = "666" });
        newList.Add(new OrderViewModel() { FirstName = "foo", ZipCode = "666" });
        newList.Add(new OrderViewModel() { FirstName = "foo" });
        newList.Add(new OrderViewModel() { FirstName = "foo", LastName = "bar", Organization = "SO", ZipCode = "666" });

        DataContext = newList;
    }
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GenerateShippingLabel(this OrderViewModel order)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (order.FirstName != "None")
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", order.FirstName);
        }
        if (order.LastName != "None")
        {
            sb.AppendLine(order.LastName);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        if (order.Organization != "None")
        {
            sb.AppendLine(order.Organization);
        }
        if (order.ZipCode != "None")
        {
            sb.AppendLine(order.ZipCode);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class ShippingLabelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is OrderViewModel)
        {
            return (value as OrderViewModel).GenerateShippingLabel();
        }
        return "None"; //isn't it ironic? ;-)
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class OrderViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public string ShippingLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GenerateShippingLabel();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ShippingLabel, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="2">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <local:ShippingLabelConverter x:Key="labelConverter" />
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource labelConverter},Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's fair, I was just trying to stick to XAML if it was possible! Good to know I wasn't too far off my reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I used a converter. Easy and clean:

```
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextAlternateConverter}">

public class TextAlternateConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

      StringBuilder myOutputText = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string param in values)
        {
            if (param == "None")
                myOutputText.Append("Give alternate text");
            else
                myOutputText.Append(param);
        }

        return myOutputText.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```